# Does openldap support pbkdf2 hash algorithm?

Tags: openldap, password, hash

Since pbkdf2 (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2) is a more secure hash function, so I wonder if current openldap implementation support pbkdf2 (pbkdf2_sha256 for example)?

I have found some information on google about pbkdf2 support in openldap, but I do not sure which openldap version it applies or I do not do it the right way:

- [(ITS#7742) New: PBKDF2 module for OpenLDAP](https://www.mail-archive.com/openldap-its@openldap.org/msg08805.html)
- [PBKDF2 for OpenLDAP](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HRFnBTIxgB0J:www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201311/msg00055.html%20&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=tw)

I have build a openldap server with version 2.4.28 on ubuntu 12.04 and use python lib to generate a PBKDF2-SHA256 hashed password. Then I put this PBKDF2-SHA256 password into a new ldap user's userPassword field as follow:

```
userPassword: '{PBKDF2-SHA256}10000$LBwTpUPGqxdH$8pDqhAruY94IhhuCZLost471pGImy//wH0pS25LO/YI='
```

This did not work. No error reported in ldap log but still can not login with the original plain-text password.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could kindly give me some comment or direction!!

Answer (score 5):

Currently, OpenLDAP PBKDF2 module only support PBKDF2-SHA1. The schema name is {PBKDF2}.
Probably, it have compatibility with Python Passlib.
I have roadmap for PBKDF2-SHA256 and PBKDF2-SHA512. but not implemented yet.

EDIT: Now supported PBKDF2-SHA256 and PBKDF2-SHA512. https://github.com/hamano/openldap-pbkdf2

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure, could please check the following:

- Did you include the directives `moduleload pw-pbkdf2.so` and `password-hash {PBKDF2}` in your `slapd.conf`?
- Did the module load correctly according to your logfiles?
- Can you generate pbkdf2-hashed password by entering `slappasswd`
- Do you get any sort of entries in your logfile regarding the faild authentication attempt?

Comment: you may add `loglevel config conn stats` to your `slapd.conf` to ease debugging the problem